# Proving $\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb E\left[ \log\left( \frac{AY+BY+N}{ AY+BY \frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}} +N } \right) \right] \leq 0$

Tags: probability, integration, derivatives

Let $X$ and $Y$ be exponentially distributed random variables with means $\theta^{-\alpha}$ and $(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}$, respectively.

Simulation results suggest that 
$$\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb E\left[ \log\left( \frac{AY+BY+N}{ AY+BY \frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}} +N } \right) \right] \leq 0$$
for $A,B,N>0.$ Does anyone know how I might prove this?

Here is what I have so far:

Letting $$I=\frac{d}{d\theta}\mathbb E\left[ \log\left( \frac{AY+BY+N}{ AY+BY \frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}} +N } \right) \right] $$ 
we have
\begin{eqnarray}I&=& \frac{d}{d\theta}\int\int \log\left( \frac{AY+BY+N}{ AY+BY \frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}} +N } \right)\frac{1}{\theta^{-\alpha}(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}} e^{-\frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}}-\frac{Y}{(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}}} dXdY\\
&=&\int\int \frac{d}{d\theta}\left[\log\left( \frac{AY+BY+N}{ AY+BY \frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}} +N } \right)\frac{1}{\theta^{-\alpha}(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}} e^{-\frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}}-\frac{Y}{(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}}}\right] dXdY\\
&=&\int\int \frac{d}{d\theta}\left[\log\left( \cdot \right)\right]\frac{1}{\theta^{-\alpha}(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}} e^{-\frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}}-\frac{Y}{(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}}}  +  \log\left( \cdot \right)\frac{d}{d\theta}\left[\frac{1}{\theta^{-\alpha}(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}} e^{-\frac{X}{\theta^{-\alpha}}-\frac{Y}{(1-\theta)^{-\alpha}}}\right] dXdY
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Hopefully you can switch the diff operator and the expectation. Then differentiate away! There is only one variable there right? Use quotient rule and all that stuff

Comment: @BCLC It's not as simple as switching the operators, I don't think. We also need to take the derivative of the density function; i.e., we need to express the expectation as an integral and then bring the diff operator inside the integral (which will act of the entire integrand).

Comment: Do the densities depend on theta? If so, go ahead and write it out. If not, try doing what I said

Comment: @BCLC They do, yes. The means are functions of $\theta$.

Comment: Uhuh...I guess this is double integral of log. Hopefully we can switch DI and diff operator. If so differentiate integrand by product rule. Can you deduce the densities from the mean?

Comment: @BCLC Three comments to say nothing useful...

Comment: To solve this, use the following steps. 1. Realize $(X,Y)$ as $X=\theta^{-\alpha}U$ and $Y=(1- \theta)^{-\alpha}V$ with $(U,V)$ i.i.d. standard exponential random variables. 2. Rewrite the ratio in the logarithm as a ratio depending on $(U,V,A,B,x)$ with $x=N(1-\theta)^\alpha$, namely, $$\frac{AV+BV+x}{AV+BUV+x}.$$ 3. Differentiate the logarithm of this with respect to $x$, which yields the derivative $$D(x)=\frac{B(U-1)V}{(AV+BV+x)(AV+BUV+x)}.$$ 4. Note that $D(x)$ is a concave function of $x$ hence Jensen yields $$E(D(x)\mid V)\leqslant \frac{B(E(U)-1)V}{(AV+BV+x)(AV+BE(U)V+x)}=0.$$ .../...

Comment: .../... 5. Conclude: the original expectation is a decreasing function of $x=N(1-\theta)^\alpha$ hence, if $\alpha>0$, it is an *increasing* function of $\theta$ (the opposite conclusion from the one you want, which one can check by considering the cases $x=0$ and $x\to\infty$).

Comment: @Did I think the post was edited after I commented. I likely would not have commented had that post been as it was now. Thanks for being such a big fan of me though ^-^

Comment: @BCLC Because your comments were useful before the edit? Sorry but you are not making any sense.